# How I set a checkbox to be always checked in WooCommerce product admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, product

How to set a checkbox to be always checked? I'm using a plugin "Woocommerce product fee" that ads a fee to products. It has a checkbox that, when is checked it calculates the fees for every product added in the cart. What I want to achieve is to set this checkbox to be always checked for every product but I can't find the right way. I added $checked but nothing happens...

This is an extract of my code:

```
    // Check Box - Fee Multiply Option
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
        'id'=> 'product-fee-multiplier[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
        'label' => __('Multiply Fee by Quantity', 'woocommerce-product-fees' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'product-fee-multiplier', true ), 
        'wrapper_class' => "product-fee-multiplier" , 
        'required'  => true
    ), $checked );

    do_action( 'wcpf_add_variation_settings' );

}

public function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    $another_field_updated = false;
    // Text Field - Fee Name
    $product_fee_name_text_field = $_POST['product-fee-name'][ $post_id ];
        if( ! empty( $product_fee_name_text_field ) || get_post_meta( 
        $post_id, 'product-fee-name', true ) != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product-fee-name', esc_attr( $product_fee_name_text_field ) );
            $another_field_updated = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Woocommerce `woocommerce_wp_checkbox()` form field function, if you wish to have the checkbox always checked by default you will use `'cbvalue'` array argument like:

```
// Check Box - Fee Multiply Option
woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
    'id'            => 'product-fee-multiplier[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
    'label'         => __('Multiply Fee by Quantity', 'woocommerce-product-fees' ),
    'value'         => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'product-fee-multiplier', true ), 
    'cbvalue'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'product-fee-multiplier', true ), 
    'wrapper_class' => "product-fee-multiplier" , 
    'required'      => true
), $checked );

do_action( 'wcpf_add_variation_settings' );
```

This will allow you to have the targeted checkbox always checked.

---

Since woocommerce 3, Here is an easy complete working example for "product" post type:

```
// Displaying quantity setting fields on admin product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_custom_field_product_options_pricing' );
function add_custom_field_product_options_pricing() {
    global $product_object;

    echo '</div><div class="options_group">';

    $values = $product_object->get_meta('_cutom_meta_key');

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( // Checkbox.
        'id'            => '_cutom_meta_key',
        'label'         => __( 'Custom label', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'         => empty($values) ? 'yes' : $values,
        'description'   => __( 'Enable this to make something.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
}

// Save quantity setting fields values
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_custom_field_product_options_pricing' );
function save_custom_field_product_options_pricing( $product ) {
    $product->update_meta_data( '_cutom_meta_key', isset($_POST['_cutom_meta_key']) ? 'yes' : 'no' );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: How to make it checked by default?

Comment: @MarcoPanichi I have added a working example for you just after my initial code

Answer (score -1):

If You try to read docs, You can see, that function `woocommerce_wp_checkbox()` has inside different parameters and use `checked()` function inside to.
So, it add checked, if  `value` = `cbvalue`.
Also, You can add custom by using param `custom_attributes`.
So, you have two ways:

```
woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
    'id'=> 'product-fee-multiplier[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
    'label' => __('Multiply Fee by Quantity', 'woocommerce-product-fees' ),
    'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'product-fee-multiplier', true ), 
    'cbvalue' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'product-fee-multiplier', true ), 
    'wrapper_class' => "product-fee-multiplier" , 
    'required'  => true
));
```

OR:

```
woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
    'id'=> 'product-fee-multiplier[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
    'label' => __('Multiply Fee by Quantity', 'woocommerce-product-fees' ),
    'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'product-fee-multiplier', true ), 
    'custom_attributes' => 'checked',
    'wrapper_class' => "product-fee-multiplier" , 
    'required'  => true
));
```

Comment: what is $variation ? this example so so bad. and awesome bad.

Comment: `$variation` is in OP's original code snippet