# Add checkbox to product inventory tab in WooCommerce and have the checkbox checked by default

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkbox, backend, product

I got this snippet in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197716/how-i-set-a-checkbox-to-be-always-checked-in-woocommerce-product-admin)  to add checkbox custom field which is auto set and it’s working fine.

```php
// Displaying quantity setting fields on admin product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_custom_field_product_options_pricing' );
function add_custom_field_product_options_pricing() {
  global $product_object;

  echo '</div><div class="options_group">';

  $values = $product_object->get_meta('_cutom_meta_key');

   woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( // Checkbox.
    'id'            => '_cutom_meta_key',
    'label'         => __( 'Custom label', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value'         => empty($values) ? 'yes' : $values,
    'description'   => __( 'Enable this to make something.', 'woocommerce' ),
   ) );
}

// Save quantity setting fields values
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_custom_field_product_options_pricing' );
function save_custom_field_product_options_pricing( $product ) {
$product->update_meta_data( '_cutom_meta_key', isset($_POST['_cutom_meta_key']) ? 'yes' : 'no');
}
```

**My question:** how to move this checkbox to be on the inventory tab and have the checkbox checked by default?

I’ve tried changing :

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_custom_field_product_options_pricing' );
```

to:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'add_custom_field_product_options_pricing' );
```

AND

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_custom_field_product_options_pricing' );
```

to:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_field_product_options_pricing' );
```

But to no avail. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` replaces the outdated `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook so you should definitely not replace it with it

To have the checkbox checked by default you can add `value` to the args from `woocommerce_wp_checkbox()`

So you get:

```php
// Add checkbox
function action_woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data() {
    global $product_object;
    
    // Get meta
    $value = $product_object->get_meta( '_cutom_meta_key' );
    
    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
        'id'            => '_cutom_meta_key', // Required, it's the meta_key for storing the value (is checked or not)
        'label'         => __( 'Custom label', 'woocommerce' ), // Text in the editor label
        'desc_tip'      => false, // true or false, show description directly or as tooltip
        'description'   => __( 'Enable this to make something', 'woocommerce' ), // Provide something useful here
        'value'         => empty( $value ) ? 'yes' : $value // Checked by default
    ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'action_woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 10, 0 );
        
// Save Field
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    // Update meta
    $product->update_meta_data( '_cutom_meta_key', isset( $_POST['_cutom_meta_key'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );
```